# XSL : Place <div /> inside <a />

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm trying to place a `<div />` tag within an `<a />` in XSL but when the page is rendered, it puts the `<a />` above the `<div />`

Been told this is not possible?

Example of what I'm trying to do:

```
<a href="{URL}" title="{Name}">
   <div class="scope">
      <div>This is clickable content on the page</div>
   </div>
</a>
```

The output for this, when rendered:

```
<a href="/route" title="Welcome"></a>
<div class="scope">
   <div>This is clickable content on the page</div>
</div>
```

**Update**

The template:

```
   <xsl:template name="BlockAnchor" match="BlockAnchor">

    <a href="{URL}" title="{Name}">
           <div class="scope">
              <div>This is clickable content on the page</div>
           </div>
        </a>    

  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you provide the xml and your current XSL attempt?

Comment: Are you sure it is an XSLT problem? How do you look at the result of your XSLT transformation? If you directly send it to the browser and then look at the document tree in the browser then you are not seeing the result of the XSLT transformation but rather the result of the HTML parser of the browser parsing the transformation result. And HTML parsers might try to correct improper nesting. So try a static HTML document with an `a` element containing `div` elements in your browser, it will probably as well correct the nesting.

Comment: Also note that in HTML 4 I think a link (`a href` element) does not allow block level element content like a `div` element while HTML5 allows that. So depending on the browser you serve your XSLT result to the browser might parse it differently.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I tried the same, obviously the nesting is wrong in HTML 4, as you cannot nest <div /> in an <a />, but in HTML 5 markup, we can do this, so I'm assuming the same here. I can do this in <span /> tags and then use jQuery to re-write the <span /> back to <div /> where necessary, but this seems like such a bad way to do it. If it is at the HTML level as suggested, then there's no way to fix this.

Comment: You can at least try to ensure that you get the nesting you want with modern browsers that support HTML5, by including the right DOCTYPE. For instance with the sample http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/html/test2013061201.html IE 10 as well as current versions of Firefox and Chrome do keep the block level `div` and `ul` inside of the `a href` element.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
     <xsl:element name="a">
         <xsl:attribute name="href">
             <xsl:value-of select="URL" />
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:attribute name="title">
             <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:element name="div">
             <xsl:attribute name="class">
                 <xsl:text>scope</xsl:text>
             </xsl:attribute>
             <xsl:element name="div">
                 <xsl:text>This is clickable content on the page</xsl:text>
             </xsl:element>
         </xsl:element>
     </xsl:element>
```

It's more verbose but it should make identical output. I just make a random guess as far as you didn't provide source xml example and full xsl.

Answer (score 0):

This is HTML5 at work. If you give it stuff that isn't valid HTML, it tries to repair it. You can't have a `<div>` inside an `<a>` element, so rather than giving you a validation error, HTML turns into something similar that is valid. It's called being liberal in what you accept.